# MOQ verify not working on void

Tags: c#, moq, verify

I have an odd problem when using moq.

In one project when I try to verify that a method has been called it says it has not. When I debug the test it clearly calls the method.

It’s a simple cache object where I want to see if I add something to the cache. I have (among others) Add, Contains and Get methods.

My verify works fine on these methods:

```
bool Contains(string key);
T Get<T>(string key);
```

But not on this:

```
void Add(string key, object objectToCache, CacheItemPolicy policy);
```

I have tried whit the exact values I give to the method as this:

```
mockedCache.Verify(p => p.Add(LOCATION_CACHE_KEY, locations, policy), Times.Once());
```

Using It.IsAny

```
mockedCache.Verify(p => p.Add(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<IEnumerable<string>>(),
     It.IsAny<CacheItemPolicy>()), Times.Once());
```

And no matter what I try I get the response that it was called 0 times.

I have never seen this behaviour before. Can anybody tell me what is wrong?

Thanks

Michael

Update:
As @SergRogovtsev suggested, I looked at the output moq generated.

My method whas not called with IEnumerable but with List

Comment: Moq tends to write what *was* called in assertion message. What was called? Also, have you tried without `Times`?

Comment: On your verify... is this a typo? `It.IsAny<string>`. It should be `It.IsAny<string>()`

Comment: Have you considered that your code is wrong and Add is not getting called?

Comment: Is there any other methods been called that haven't been mocked before reaching this method?

Comment: It.IsAny<IEnumerable<string>>(), try replacing that with Object may be

Comment: Have you tried calling Verify with the following parameters:mockedCache.Verify(p => p.Add(It.IsAny<string>, It.IsAny<object>(),
     It.IsAny<CacheItemPolicy>()), Times.Once()); ?

Comment: @Claudio Redi That was a typo - I have updated it.

Comment: @cadrell0 When I step debug I hit Add, så I don't think thats the error

Comment: @SergRogovtsev Thanks! I did not see I wrote output for all that have been called. I have updated, the question.

Comment: @AD.Net and Jakub Kaleta That did not work

Answer (score 0):

As you've seen, Moq is not checking the exact types of the parameters passed, not just that they derive from the type you are asserting. If you want that functionality you may need to use something like this:

```
mockedCache.Verify(p => p.Add(It.IsAny<string>(), It.Is<object>(o => o is IEnumerable<string>), It.IsAny<CacheItemPolicy>()), Times.Once());
```

Otherwise you could look into getting an updated version of Moq - I have tested your original scenario (using `It.IsAny<IEnumerable<string>>` in the assertion) and it works correctly with Moq v4.0)

Answer (score 0):

Does `CacheItemPolicy` implements an interface? If so, will you try verifying the call with

```
mockedCache.Verify(p => p.Add(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<IEnumerable<string>>(), It.IsAny<ICacheItemPolicy>()), Times.Once());
```

or whatever the interface's name is?

I had the same problem. Thing is, my SUT method received an interface, and that's what it passed to the mocked object. Though the class may implement the interface, the interface is still a different type. Hope this helps.